# Adding elements to a newly defined list in Racket

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, dot-product

I am new to Racket and functional languages in general. For now I am just trying to prepend items to a list. The concepts are a bit confusing and not sure why my code isn't working.

I am trying to do dot product calculations.

I have a function called "dProduct" that takes 2 lists (A and B) and multiplies each corresponding element in them.

```
    ;function takes dot product
    (define (dProduct A B)

      (define C '()) ; define list to store the multiplied elements

      ;multiply ea lists elements
      (for ([i A] [j B])
        (display (* i j))   ;THIS WORKS
        (cons (* i j) C)    ;APPARENTLY DOESN'T WORK
      )

      ;THIS FOR LOOP DISPLAYS NOTHING
      ;display the new list "C"
      (for ([k C])
        (display k)
      )

    )
```

I don't understand why I can't use cons to prepend the new multiplied elements to my new list "C". What am I missing? Everything compiles fine. Would like to figure this out so I can finish this function :) Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Free Scheme books: [How to Design Programs](http://www.htdp.org) (also linked to from DrRacket's builtin help, which is excellent in itself); [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html).

Answer (score 4):

Lists are immutable, and `cons` does *not* prepend an element to an existing list. Instead, it produces a new list with the element prepended:

```
> (define x '(2 3))
> (cons 1 x)
'(1 2 3)
> x
'(2 3)
```

Since your question is tagged [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming), I will assume that you probably want to know how to do this functionally, and functional programming generally discourages mutating values or bindings.

Instead of mutating a binding, you should build up a new structure functionally. The easiest way to do this is to change your use of `for` to `for/list`, which produces a list of return values:

```
(define C
  (for/list ([i A] [j B])
    (* i j)))
```

For this program, you could make it even simpler by using the higher-order function `map`, which acts like a “zip” when provided more than one list argument:

```
(define C (map * A B))
```

Since `for` always returns `#<void>`, it’s only useful for producing side-effects, and in functional programming, you generally try and keep side-effects to a minimum. For that reason, you will likely find that `for/list` and `for/fold` are actually much more commonly useful in idiomatic Racket than plain `for` is.

Answer (score -1):

Current `C` list has to be given new value of `(cons (* i j) C)` and this can be done using `set!` :

```
(define (dProduct A B)

  (define C '()) 

  (for ([i A] [j B])
    (displayln (* i j))          
    (set! C (cons (* i j) C)))   ; NOTE set! HERE.

  (for ([k C])
    (displayln k)))
```

Note that the use of `set!` is strongly discouraged and `for/list` is much better way to achieve desired result here.